# Remove optionsCaption from select tag using knockout JS

Tags: javascript, select, knockout.js

How to remove the `optionsCaption` from `select tag ?` using `knockout JS`

My `select tag` is like :

```
<select data-bind="options: categories, optionsText: 'type', optionsCaption: 'Select Any Ticket type', value: chosenCategory, disable: showReservationDetails, event: {change: calRemainingTickets}"></select>
```

It shows `Select Any Ticket` as first `option`. `on change` of the `select tag` i want to remove the `Select Ant Ticket option`.

How can we `remove` that `required option` from `select tag ?`

Thank you in Advance .

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can bind optionsCaption to an observable and set the observable's value to undefined. I've modified Joe's code to do this.

```js
var vm = function () {
    this.optionsCaption = ko.observable('Select any');
    this.categories = ko.observableArray([ {type: 'Type 1' }, { type: 'Type 2' }]);
    this.chosenCategory = ko.observable('Select Any Ticket type');
    this.showReservationDetails = ko.observable(false);
    this.calRemainingTickets = function () {
        this.optionsCaption(undefined);
    }.bind(this);
}

ko.applyBindings(new vm());
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.0.0/knockout-min.js"></script>
<select data-bind="options: categories, optionsCaption: optionsCaption, optionsText: 'type', value: chosenCategory, disable: showReservationDetails, event: {change: calRemainingTickets}"></select>
```

Comment: Hi `Roy J`,  If we want to add `Select` again `on click ` of an `<a> tag` what should we do ?
I tried like `on click` of `<a> tag` i called an `function` and written below code
 `this.optionsCaption('Select')` but it is not usefull .

Comment: Very nice and cleaner I think +1

Answer (score 0):

[Example] http://jsfiddle.net/cg988b4n/

It's a little *smoke-and-mirror-y*. But it works by not using `optionsCaption`. The change event removes that default options on the first change. Your logic `typeId === -1` will have to change to use whatever fits with your logic.

My view model

```
var vm = function () {
    this.categories = ko.observableArray([{ type: 'Select Any Ticket type', typeId: -1 }, {type: 'Type 1' }, { type: 'Type 2' }]);
    this.chosenCategory = ko.observable('Select Any Ticket type');
    this.showReservationDetails = ko.observable(false);
    this.calRemainingTickets = function () {
        if (this.categories()[0].typeId === -1) {
            this.categories.shift();   
        }
    }.bind(this);
}

ko.applyBindings(new vm());
```

Answer (score 0):

Knockout will insert the caption option on `applyBindings`, but you can certainly remove it afterward without affecting your viewmodel or KO complaining. A solution like Joe's that inserts the placeholder option into the viewmodel would work, but personally I'd prefer to keep that out of my data and would instead do something like this:

```
vm.calRemainingTickets = function (data, event) {
    var el = event.target.options[0];
    el.value || el.remove();
    // whatever else needs doing
};
```

What this does is remove the first option child of the bound select element if it has a falsy option value, which your `optionsCaption` would. You could also check instead for `text === 'Select Any Ticket type'` or set a "has already removed the first element" flag.

Answer (score 0):

You can restore it this way:

```js
var vm = function () {
    this.optionsCaption = ko.observable('Select any');
    this.categories = ko.observableArray([ {type: 'Type 1' }, { type: 'Type 2' }]);
    this.chosenCategory = ko.observable('Select Any Ticket type');
    this.showReservationDetails = ko.observable(false);
    this.calRemainingTickets = function () {
        this.optionsCaption(undefined);
    }.bind(this);
    this.putItBack = function() {
      this.optionsCaption('Select Any');
    }
}

ko.applyBindings(new vm());
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.0.0/knockout-min.js"></script>
<select data-bind="options: categories, optionsCaption: optionsCaption, optionsText: 'type', value: chosenCategory, disable: showReservationDetails, event: {change: calRemainingTickets}"></select>
<a href="#" data-bind="click:putItBack">Put It Back</a>
```